# How I can use external javascript file in HTML 5 (On Inkling Platform)

Tags: html

When I am using 'onclick(myFunction())', it is showing error that onclick() is not allowed.

Which type of change required here?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

change onclick(myFunction()) to onclick="myFunction()"

Moreover, you have not included any code so I cannot tell how you are linking your js file but make sure you are linking the html to your js file.

Change the following code to match your file name. Also make sure your .html .css and .js files are in the same folder.  Its good practice.

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" designation="" enumeration="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" href="../../assets/widgets/zoomify/js/zoomifyimageviewer.js" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/widgets/zoomify/css/edit.css" />
        <title>Zoomify</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
            <button onclick="Z.showImage()">World map</button>
        -->
        <div id="myContainer"></div>
        <p class="Z.showImage">World Map</p>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Now, please confirm that how I can call mu function here. Because When I  am using onclick="Z.showImage()", It shows invalid tag error.

Comment: Hey Vikas what does Z. refer too?  Can you create a jsfiddle for this program so I can see how it works? From looking at your button tag, I would just call the show image function as onclick="showImage()"

Comment: (function(){var e=function(){return this}.call();e.Z={}})(),Z.showImage=function(e,t,n){Z.Utils.z202(),Z.Utils.z201(),Z.Utils.z200(),Z.Utils.z258(),Z.z361=e,Z.imagePath=Z.Utils.z392(t),Z.parameters=Z.Utils.z368(n),Z.Utils.addEventListener(document,"DOMContentLoaded",Z.initialize),Z.Utils.addEventListener(window,"load",Z.initialize)}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ copy your html code into the html box, copy your js code into the js box and css into css box. When done, click save then share. copy the link from the share link box and then add that link in your next comment.

Comment: You really need to format your code... Its very hard to follow.

Comment: I got this from a project. And Now I have to use it on Inkling Platform. Please suggest which type of changes required here. Actually I am doing a project where "Zoom and Pan" for image is required. Could you please help me for this?

Comment: As far as your original question goes, just make sure you link your javascript properly.  Reference your methods or functions correctly.  That's all the help I can give with the limited view of this code.  Did you write all the projects code yourself ?

Comment: Yes, Please provide certain type of code or reference for any other site.